# Position_dodge with preserve='single' do not align geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2, positioning, geom-text

Any ideas on how to solve the missialingment of text summary?
why position_dodge works well for error_bar but not for text??
I have also tried position_dodge2. It also gives lots of problems with error_bar positions....

```
ggplot(data=data_areas[data_areas$TIMEPOINT=='0h',], aes(ISOFORM,NEURITE_CELL_AREA_RATIOP)) +
geom_bar(aes(fill=CELLTYPE,color=CELLTYPE), position=position_dodge(width=0.9, preserve = "single"), width=0.8,stat = 'summary', fun.y = 'mean') +
geom_errorbar(aes(color = CELLTYPE), stat = 'summary',position=position_dodge(width=0.9, preserve = "single"), width = 0.2,size=2, fun.data = "mean_sdl", fun.args = list(mult = 1)) + # mult indica el numero de desviaciones estandar
#geom_point(aes(group=CELLTYPE), shape = 21, position = position_dodge(.8), size=2, fill="gray")+
scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.5,0.05))+
scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.05,0), limits = c(0, 25), breaks = seq(0, 25, by = 5))+
scale_fill_manual(name="Celltype",values =c("#7d7973","#7d7973","#7d7973","#7d7973","#7d7973","#7d7973","#7d7973"))+
scale_color_manual(name="Celltype",values =c("#7d7973","#7d7973","#7d7973","#7d7973","#7d7973","#7d7973","#7d7973"))+
stat_summary(aes(label=round(..y..,2),group=CELLTYPE), fun.y=mean, geom="text", size=4,color="red",position=position_dodge(width=0.9, preserve='single'), vjust = 2)+
theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
      axis.title.y =element_blank(),
      axis.text.x  = element_blank(),
      axis.text.y  = element_blank(),
      plot.margin = margin(1, 1, 1, 1, "cm"),
      axis.line.y = element_line(colour = "black", size=1),
      axis.line.x =  element_line(colour = "black", size=1),
      axis.ticks = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.5),
      axis.ticks.length = unit(10, "pt"),
      axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
      legend.position="none",
      panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'),
      panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#f0f0f0"))
```

[image: plot obtained]

Comment: Hello! Please provide the reproducible sample.

Comment: Yes, a reproducible example would help. You could try `position_dodge2' as well perhaps.